# Conditional replacement of a comma with a dot in a numeric column

Tags: r, gsub, data-cleaning

I am currently cleaning some German data. German data is formatted differently from the normal. In German, thousand with two decimals is 1.000,00
In English, it is 1,000.00
I would like to first remove the dot in the 1.000,00 and then replace the comma with a dot, but only when there exists both a comma and a dot in the number. 
If the number just has a dot and no comma, then I would like to preserve the dot.

I tried a normal gsub, but of course it is not conditional

```
tidy$obs_values<-as.character(gsub(",",".",tidy$obs_values))
```

In short, what I need is:

```
#input
raw$obs_values<-c(1.000,00 , 8.3 , 2.900,00 , 9.2)

#output
raw$obs_values<-c(1000.00 , 8.3 , 2900.00 , 9.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a logical condition with `as.numeric` and `is.na` as conversion to `numeric` returns `NA` if the value is not a legitimate numeric syntax.  In the example, the first and third elements have `,`, so it is interpreted as `character` and thus gives `NA`.  Using `is.na`, construct a logical vector and then apply the replacement logic with `sub` on the subset vector.  Though, it can be done with `grep` as well

```
i1 <- is.na(as.numeric(str1))
str1[i1] <- sub(",", ".", sub("\\.", "", str1[i1]))
str1
#[1] "1000.00" "8.3"     "2900.00" "9.2"
```

Note that converting to `numeric` will remove the trailing zero digits

```
as.numeric(str1)
#[1] 1000.0    8.3 2900.0    9.2
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('1.000,00', 8.3, '2.900,00', 9.2)
```

Comment: @NelsonGon. I added some more description.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very sketchy `stringr` attempt:

```
raw<-c("1.000,00" , "8.3" , "2.900,00" , "9.2")
new<-str_replace_all(raw,",(?=0)",".")
str_remove_all(new,".(?=\\d{3,})")

[1] "1000.00" "8.3"     "2900.00" "9.2"
```

Or more generally as suggested by @akrun
You can replace d with  [0-9]

```
new1<-str_replace_all(raw,",(?=\\d)",".")
    str_remove_all(new1,".(?=\\d{3,})")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.  We can split each term on comma, and then remove dots for those numbers which have a comma/decimal component.  For those numbers which don't have a comma, we just use the original value.

```
obs_values <- c("1.000,00", "8.3", "2.900,00", "9.2")

output <- sapply(obs_values, function(x) {
    parts <- strsplit(x, ",")[[1]]
    return(ifelse(length(parts) > 1,
                  paste0(gsub("\\.", "", parts[1]), ".", parts[2]),
                  parts[1]))
})

output

 1.000,00       8.3  2.900,00       9.2 
"1000.00"     "8.3" "2900.00"     "9.2"
```